# How can we change a linkbutton to a hyperlink with variables?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm not very familiar with ASPX, not enough to get my head around this.

Our developers have used this code in a gridview control which opens a new tab and sends the user to a "details" page.

```
<asp:LinkButton Text='<%# Bind("OrderId") %>' CommandArgument='<%# Bind("FormId") %>' ID="lnkOrderId" runat="server" OnClick="lnkOrderId_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
```

This code produces HTML that looks like this:

```
<a id="gvGridView_lnkOrderId_2" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;gvGridView$ctl04$lnkOrderId&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">20109</a>
```

To be able to use a Jquery fancybox control, we need the code to produce the code like this:

```
<a id="gvGridView_lnkOrderId_2"  href=”http://domain.com/Details.aspx?OrderId=20109&FormId=0”>20109</a>
```

I can see we need to use `asp:hyperlink`, but what I tried with the variable doesn't work.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: use `PostBackUrl` attribute of `LinkButton`

Comment: What you have tried so far, Plz share piece of your code,

Comment: The PostBackUrl, make postback, is not a simple followed link...

Answer (score 0):

I use a `TemplateField`and direct render the link, here is how:

On the GridView aspx page I use:

```
<asp:TemplateField >
    <ItemTemplate >
      <%#LinkToGoto(Container.DataItem)%>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

and on code behind I make the link as:

```
protected string LinkToGoto(object oItem) 
{
    // read the data from database
    var cOrderId = (int)DataBinder.Eval(oItem, "OrderId");

    // format and render back the link
    return String.Format("<a href=\"http://domain.com/Details.aspx?OrderId={0}\">go to order</a>", OrderId);
}
```

Comment: Why this? `<a>` tag can be added directly into the `GridView` without making an extra call to server side.

Comment: @Bharadwaj There is not any extra call to the server side !

Comment: `LinkToGoto` is a method in `c#`

Comment: @Bharadwaj This is a method that is called when the page is rendered !. Nothing to do with extra call to the server side. Please check that out, read the asp.net manual, see some tutorial, make some test... learn it

Comment: Every time a row is created, you are saying this method won't call? for every row which is rendered, this method will sure get called!

Comment: @Bharadwaj Yes, but this is done when the page is rendered ones and for all, in the server side, the results are go to the page... Then the user click on the link and go to some other page. No extra call to the server side... maybe we do not speak the same language.. what is the extra call to the server side ?. Please make a test with this code and see whats and how is work.... please.

Comment: OP is using `GridView` which means it is not once and for all! every time it is get binded, rows will be created!

Comment: @Bharadwaj Pointless, we do not speak the same language... please give your answer, and leave me alone.

Comment: I'm trying it anyway.